# GoogleApi Don't Show ads Using CURL

Tags: php, ads

I am using googleapi using CURL but I am not able to get ads in results. Is it possible to activate the ads?

Comment: ads load after the page is loaded, ie. via JS so no not possible directly (as they track your domain and other stuffs). You can try iframes but again, that could be against google's terms. Becareful with it.

Comment: Which Google API exactly? Can you post a code example?

Comment: thanks for your comment Sugato but I want to do this using PHP API as I have done this using JS before

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far..

Comment: curl  -k "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/
v1?key=fd&cfdff4545fdsf45f4dsffdfx=464545465456465:o_moiu4545454w_
eik&q=each+indexed+field+in+the+document,+MongoDB+multiplies+the+number"

Chirki this is my query

Comment: If I query the same text using browser then I got ads but if I do this using CURL then I am able to get results other then ads

Comment: Actually it is very unlikely that you will get a solution. You are querying the non JS version of google ( as your client is curl) which might or might not serve ads. With that, scraping google search result is against their TOS ( funny, eh? :P ) anyway..

Comment: if you are making a query using their api, then you would be fine though, but i don't think they will serve ads.

Comment: I done this using fake firefox more funny

Answer (score 0):

You cant, there is no way you get ads in results via googleapis json/atom api. Google has not mentioned in their API documentation about results. Also You can see API's [Response](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response) result, there is not such thing like ads.